# Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support - Installing Django Cms

Tags: macos, django-cms, libjpeg, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get Django Cms to work on my system.
Following the Django-CMS tutorial: https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial

I had to install pillow, but now when i run:

```
$ djangocms -p . my_demo
```

and fill in all the options i get the following error:

```
HTTP error 404 while getting https://github.com/divio/django-cms/archive/3.0c2.zip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
do_download,
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
self.session,
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 547, in unpack_http_url
resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 773, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/macbook/.pip/pip.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 24, in execute
install.check_install(config_data)
  File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/MyProjects/djangoCMS/demo/demoEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/install/__init__.py", line 54, in check_install
raise EnvironmentError("\n".join(errors))
EnvironmentError: Pillow is not compiled with JPEG support, see 'Libraries installation issues' documentation section.
```

While searching the web i found that i had to install `libjpeg`.

Even after doing so i got the same error. Now i don't get it to work and i really want to get working with Django CMS. quite sure i did something wrong while installing `libjpeg`. But i'm now quite sure how to get going now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has a similar problem. Here is how I proceeded to get rid of it.

1. Install Pillow with all of the necessary dependences.
   You can refer to this [link](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) 
   If you are running on mac, it's simply type the following commands
   $ brew install libtiff libjpeg webp little-cms2
   $ pip install Pillow
2. If you observe well, you will notice that there has been an error when the program tried to reach github.com/divio/django-cms/archive/3.0c2.zip
   You need to remove the "c2" to remain with github.com/divio/django-cms/archive/3.0.zip

To edit that, go to /env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/config
Where env is the environment you are using(if you are using virtualenv. Just find your site-packages directory)

Open data.py and change the 7th line as described above. You may need to change permissions of the file to be able to edit it.

From now on, it should be working well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

my case:

diagnose with followed command:

```
python -c 'from PIL import Image'
```

Reason: Incompatible library version: libtiff.5.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0

solution:

```
pip uninstall PIL
pip uninstall Pillow

brew uninstall libpng
brew uninstall libjpeg
brew uninstall webp
brew uninstall libtiff
brew uninstall littlecms
brew prune => to clean symlink

brew install  libjpeg webp libtiff littlecms libpng

pip install Pillow
```

if libpng error as: Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/libpng/libpng16/1.6.13/libpng-1.6.13.tar.xz

```
cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew
download the package from browser and copy here
brew install libpng
```